# ArcObjects, "License not intialized" error, but it should be initialized

Tags: arcobjects

In my VB.NET application, I am using ArcObjects 10.4 and I am initializing ArcGIS. I load a feature class from a shapefile. The problem is that I get an HRESULT error 0x80040228, which is 2147220952 in decimal and it means "License not intialized" as you can see on this website: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000000mn000000

The strange thing is, I load two feature classes. One from a shapefile, then another from a file geodatabase. As I said, loading from the shapefile crashes, but not from the FGDB. Also, if I invert the two LoadFeatureLayer lines, the FGDB feature class loads, and then, the shapefile feature class loads too. I tried with different features classes, the result is the same.

Is it a normal behavior?

```
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem

Public Class frm_Loading
Public aoInit As IAoInitialize

Private Sub frm_Loading_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    InitializeArcGIS()
    LoadFeatureLayer("export_output_2.shp", "c:\temp")
    LoadFeatureLayer("C_R137_CH", "c:\temp\FGDB.gdb", True)
End Sub

Public Sub InitializeArcGIS()
    If aoInit Is Nothing Then
        If ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.ActiveRuntime Is Nothing Then
            ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.BindLicense(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.Desktop)
        End If

        aoInit = New AoInitialize
        aoInit.Initialize(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeBasic)
    End If
End Sub

Public Function LoadFeatureLayer(ByVal layer As String, ByVal cheminWorkspace As String, Optional FGDB As Boolean = False) As IFeatureLayer
    Dim aWorkspaceFactory As IWorkspaceFactory = Nothing
    Dim aFeatureWorkspace As IFeatureWorkspace = Nothing
    Dim aFeatureLayer As IFeatureLayer
    Try
        If FGDB Then
            Dim t As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory")
            Dim obj As System.Object = Activator.CreateInstance(t)
            aWorkspaceFactory = obj
        Else
            Dim t As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriDataSourcesFile.ShapefileWorkspaceFactory")
            Dim obj As System.Object = Activator.CreateInstance(t)
            aWorkspaceFactory = obj
        End If
        aFeatureWorkspace = aWorkspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(cheminWorkspace, 0)
        aFeatureLayer = New FeatureLayer
        aFeatureLayer.FeatureClass = aFeatureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass(layer)
        aFeatureLayer.Name = aFeatureLayer.FeatureClass.AliasName
        Return aFeatureLayer

    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(ex.ToString)
        Return Nothing
    Finally
        If aWorkspaceFactory IsNot Nothing Then System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(aWorkspaceFactory)
        If aFeatureWorkspace IsNot Nothing Then System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(aFeatureWorkspace)
    End Try
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: If you can create a WorkspaceFactory then I would expect your license is working. What line actually throws the exception when it fails? Also try removing the '.shp' from your call to LoadFeatureLayer.

Comment: The error happens at the line aWorkspaceFactory.OpenFromFile. I also tried to remove the SHP and it changes nothing.

Comment: I have tested and run your code and run it without any issues (shapefile first). Have you tested any other shapefiles? ArcMap does give unrelated error messages from time to time.

Comment: I tested other shapefiles and it doesn't work. But I have just tested it on a machine with ArcGIS 10.2 and it works. It feels like a ArcGIS 10.4 problem. I will try other 10.4 machines and if it is still not working, I will send this case to ESRI. Thank you!